# bash how to close /dev/tty?

Tags: linux, bash, tty

I want my interactive bash to run a program that will ultimately do things like:
    echo Error: foobar >/dev/tty
and in another(python) component tries to prompt for and read a password from /dev/tty.
I want such reads and writes to fail, but not block.
Is there some way to close /dev/tty in the parent script and then run the program?
I tried 
    foo >&/tmp/outfile

which does not work.
What does sort of work is the 'at' command:
    at now
    at> foobar >&/tmp/outfile

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/tty` is not open in your parent script. `/dev/tty` isn't a file descriptor but a path in the filesystem.

A line of script such as:

```
echo foobar > /dev/tty
```

opens a new descriptor for itself.  To make that fail, we have to remove `/dev/tty`, or otherwise not make it work: change the permissions, or replace it with a nonexistent device. Needless to say, these are bad ideas.

If we want to run a script which does some useful things for us, but also does I/O to and from `/dev/tty` that we don't want (and we cannot change the script), the solutions range from creating an environment for that script in which the controlling terminal is some pseudo-tty (whose master side just throws data away), to doing a `chroot` to an environment in which `/dev/tty` is the same device as `/dev/null`.

Regarding the first option, there are utilities which create a pseudo tty, such as Expect.

For instance:

```
$ expect -c "spawn ./badscript ; expect"
```

will run `badscript` in an environment where its `/dev/tty` is a pseudo-tty that is connected to the `expect` interpreter. An `echo foo > /dev/tty` issued by `badscript` will still show up on your terminal, but now how it gets to your terminal is that `expect` reads it from `badscript` via the pseudo-tty device, and then repeats it; `badscript` is blocked from writing to your `tty` directly. Of course, with some scripting in expect's language, you can prevent this.

Comment: I see, that helps a lot.  Unfortunately, I cannot install expect(or pexpect) on our myriad servers... is there a way to do this with the python(builtin) 'pty' module?

Comment: @GeorgeYoung No idea, but if not, that module hardly lives up to the bold acronym PTY. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`/dev/tty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) refers to the controlling terminal of the process. If you mean to get rid of it by describing it as **closing**, you must invoke [`setsid()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) which will make the process be controlling TTY-less, but one must be aware to always pass [`O_NOCTTY`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) else a opened file, if a TTY, can become the controlling TTY.<sup>[[2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)]</sup>